# How to merge two .yaml files such that shared keys between the files uses only one of their values?

Tags: yaml, yq

I am attempting to merge two yaml files and would like any shared keys under a specific key to use values from one of the yaml files, and not merge both. This problem may be better described using an example. GIven file1.yaml and file2.yaml, I am trying to achieve the following:

file1.yaml

```
name: 'file1'
paths:
  path1: 
    content: "t"
  path2:
    content: "b"
```

file2.yaml

```
name: 'file2'
paths:
  path1: 
    value: "t"
```

My ideal result in merging is the following file:

file3.yaml

```
name: 'file2'
paths:
  path1: 
    value: "t"
  path2:
    content: "b"
```

Specifically, I would like to overwrite any key under paths such that if both yaml files have the same key under paths, then only use the value from file2. Is there some tool that enables this? I was looking into yq but I'm not sure if that tool would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq you are using. They are quite similar, but sometimes differ a lot.

For instance, using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you can use `input` to access the second file, which you can provide alongside the first one:

```bash
yq -y 'input as $in | .name = $in.name | .paths += $in.paths' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

```yaml
name: file2
paths:
  path1:
    value: t
  path2:
    content: b
```

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you'd use `load` with providing the second file in the code, while only the first one is your regular input:

```bash
yq 'load("file2.yaml") as $in | .name = $in.name | .paths += $in.paths' file1.yaml
```

```yaml
name: 'file2'
paths:
  path1:
    value: "t"
  path2:
    content: "b"
```